# D3 Map - feeding data to tootip

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to adapt to my needs [this](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/a74faf20b492ad377312) very neat example based on this [dataset](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/raw/a74faf20b492ad377312/3513ad985b2fa93ea35f2fc864cb30540c298171/uStates.js).

Instead of randomly generated data:

```
           var low=Math.round(100*Math.random()), 
           mid=Math.round(100*Math.random()), 
           high=Math.round(100*Math.random());`
```

I would like to display some of the properties e.g. real population or area of the state. I was trying to add properties to each line in uStates.js

```
{id:"OH",n:"Ohio", pop:"11.59", area:"116,096", d:"M735.32497,(..),193.32832Z"},
```

and plug it to `tooltipHTML` function

```
           function tooltipHtml(n, d, pop, area)
           return "<h4>"+n+"</h4><table>"+
           "<tr><td> Population </td><td>"+pop+"</td></tr>"+
           "<tr><td> Area </td><td>"+area+"</td></tr>"+
           "</table>";
```

but it doesn't work (in place of a value an `undefined` appears).

My native software is **R**. I did not find a suitable solution there thus I am trying my luck with Javascript to which I know very little. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Can you share your attempt for your custom `tooltipHTML` function? This is the right approach, so it would help to know where is the error.

Comment: hi laurent, just made an update and added tooltipHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use `uStates.js` seamlessly, your own data should be separated from the path coordinates (in short: *do not edit uStates.js*).

The format for your data should be:

```
 var data={
     "OH": {pop:"11.59", area:"116,096", color:"#FFF"},
     "NY": { ... },
     ...
    };
```

The `color` field is mandatory for uStates to work. You can make it fit your other values automatically, and you can also convert your data to this format if you have it in another way (but this is not the scope of this answer, don't hesitate to ask for more about this).

Then, you only need to edit the `tooltipHTML` function to take the `pop` and `area` fields of your data (`d`):

```
    function tooltipHtml(n, d) {
       return "<h4>"+n+"</h4><table>"+
       "<tr><td>Low Low Low</td><td>"+d.pop+"</td></tr>"+
       "<tr><td>Average Average</td><td>"+d.area+"</td></tr>"+
       "</table>";
    }
```

Finally, call uStates with

```
  uStates.draw("#statesvg", data, tooltipHtml);
```

Comment: thank you so much **laurent**! it worked like charm.

Comment: i have just upvoted you answer. i have another issue with regards to this example and dataset formulated in another thread: excluding a polygon from hovering. perhaps it would fall in scope of your interest.

Comment: Don't hesitate to accept the answer if it solves your problem ;)