# D3 map - excluding a polygon from hovering

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In a follow up to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35723052/d3-map-feeding-data-to-tootip) I am trying to adopt to my needs this great [example](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/a74faf20b492ad377312) of a  map (working with this [dataset](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/raw/a74faf20b492ad377312/3513ad985b2fa93ea35f2fc864cb30540c298171/uStates.js)) and opening a custom tooltip upon hovering.

I would like to exclude from hovering some states.

I want them to appear on a map but as gray and non-responsive.

If I were working with `svg path` I would define a different css `class` for polygons/states with hovering and a different class just for the non-responsive.

I don't know how to do it in this case where my paths are encapsulated in a variable ([dataset](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/raw/a74faf20b492ad377312/3513ad985b2fa93ea35f2fc864cb30540c298171/uStates.js)).

```
function(){
var uStatePaths={id:"HI",n:"Hawaii",d:"M233.08751,(...),554.06663Z"}, (...)
{id:"VT",n:"Vermont",d:"M844.48416,(...),154.05791Z"}, (...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak the file uStates.js to achieve what you want. Create a duplicate of the `draw()` method and apply some changes:

- Pass a list of the states IDs that you want to "disable".
- If the ID of the state is in the list, instead of using the defined `fill`, use a "disabled gray" color.
- In the event controllers, check if the state ID is in the list; and if it is, don't apply the changes (as the state will be "disabled").

The function would be like this:

```
// notice the new parameter "list" that will contain the disabled states
uStates.drawSpecial = function(id, data, toolTip, list){        

    function mouseOver(d){
      // only show the tooltip if the state is not in the disabled list
      if (list.indexOf(d.id) < 0) {
        d3.select("#tooltip").transition().duration(200).style("opacity", .9);      
        d3.select("#tooltip").html(toolTip(d.n, data[d.id]))  
            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")     
            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
        }
    }

    function mouseOut(){
        d3.select("#tooltip").transition().duration(500).style("opacity", 0);      
    }

    d3.select(id).selectAll(".state")
        .data(uStatePaths)
        .enter()
        .append("path")
        .attr("class","state")
        .attr("d",function(d){ return d.d;})
        // if the state id is in the list, select gray instead of the state color
        .style("fill",function(d){ return list.indexOf(d.id) >= 0 ? "#dddddd" : data[d.id].color; })
        .on("mouseover", mouseOver).on("mouseout", mouseOut);
}
```

Then instead of calling the `draw` method, call your own personlized `drawSpecial` method. For example, in a similar code to the one found in the [tutorial you linked](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/a74faf20b492ad377312), if you want to disable Texas (TX) and Vermont (VT), you'd call the function like this:

```
uStates.draw("#statesvg", sampleData, tooltipHtml, ['TX', 'VT']);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need  a way to say if a given state is gray or active. The direct way to do that is to add an `active` field in your data, which is either `true`or  `false`.

Then, you draw the map as before (using `uStates.draw`). After that, you can paint the inactive states in gray and remove the mouseover and  mouseout events as follows:

```
  d3.selectAll(".state") //select all state objects
    .filter(function(d) { return !data[d.id].active }) //keep only inactives:
          //d.id  is the state id, 
          //data[d.id]  fetches your piece of data related to this state, and     
          //!data[d.id].active  gives the negation of the newly created active flag
    .style("fill", function(d){ return "#888" }) // paint in gray
    .on("mouseover", null) //remove mouseover events
    .on("mouseout", null); //remove mouseout events
```

Comment: thank you very much for all the replies and answers!