# D3 map - combine two disjoint svg polygon paths into one path

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

This is my 3rd follow up question on the [interactive map](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/a74faf20b492ad377312) with tooltip.

The original map used USA states coordinates. I am trying to build a map of Europe (hence my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35724822/d3-map-excluding-a-polygon-from-hovering) on excluding some polygons from hovering to draw the physical shape of the continent but allow a tooltip only above EU members only).

In my work I initially inspired myself by [Peter Collingridge svg tutorial](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/svg-tutorial)  where most country polygons are expressed in `svg paths`. For the [source](http://www.petercollingridge.co.uk/data-visualisation/choropleth-maps-africa) of **SVG maps** he is advising Wikimedia and there I found a [Firefox Mozilla Europe map](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Map_of_Europe_-Mozilla_Firefox.svg) with very well defined [country paths](http://view-source:https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8c/Map_of_Europe_-Mozilla_Firefox.svg).

Everything was going well until I stumbled on two countries: Russia and Great Britain.

In the original [USA dataset](http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/raw/a74faf20b492ad377312/3513ad985b2fa93ea35f2fc864cb30540c298171/uStates.js) even states composed of multiple polygons such as Massachusets are expressed with one unique **d:** property.

```
{id:"MA",n:"Massachusets", d:"M899.62349,(...), 153.35923L855.45082,152.06593Z"},
```

whereas the above mentioned UK and Russia are expressed with two distinct **d**s:

```
<g id="ru" transform="matrix(1.43317, 0, 0, 1.43317, -2435.49, -1086.58)">
<path id="ru-main" d="M 9462.6109,(...),2763.2929 z "/>
<path id="ru-kgd"  d="M 6989.6109,(...),3728.389 z "/>
</g>
```

plus there is this attribute `transform = "matrix(...)"`

This problem I have solved by applying [this tool](http://petercollingridge.appspot.com/svg-transforms) nonetheless in the Mozilla Firefox map Russia is composed of two paths with two separate ids: `id="ru-main"` and `id="ru-kgd"`same thing for **UK**.

I'd like to make sure that whenever a user is hovering above mainland Russian or Kaliningrad strip the entire territory of Russia gets highlighted.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to make sure that whenever a user is hovering above mainland Russian or Kaliningrad strip the entire territory of Russia gets highlighted.
>
> Is there a way to do it?

What you want to do is to watch the mouse event at country (`<g>`) level, and apply the hover effect to all the hovered `<g>`'s children `<path>` elements.

```
var countries= d3.selectAll('g')

countries.on('mouseenter', function(d, i) { //mouse starts hovering a country's shape

  d3.select(this)             // select the hovered country
    .selectAll('path')        // select all its children paths
    .style('fill', '#75D9FA') // apply desired effect to the paths
})

countries.on('mouseleave', function(d, i) { //mouse stops hovering a country's shape
  // follow same logic as above to reset original style
  d3.select(this)
    .selectAll('path')
    .style('fill', '#24BDF0')
})
```

Here is a [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/ZAljuXx251ply8JJ65Xg?p=preview) using a data structure similar to the one presented in your question.